# ssh to server and auto execute sudo command and keep the shell open

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

I want an `alias` on my local machine that will `ssh` to the target system, execute `sudo` using the password stored on my local machine, but leave the shell open on the remote system.  The reason is I'm lazy and every time I log into a server I don't want to type my very long password.  I'm aware that this is not the safest of practices.

Right now it works if I do the following:

```
ssh -q -t $1 "echo $mypword|base64 -d|sudo -S ls; bash -l"
```

`$1` being the host name of the remote system.  mypword is my encoded password stored on my local system.  This works and leaves my shell open.  I can then do anything with sudo because it is now cached for that shell.

The problem I have is if you do a ps and grep for my account you will see the encoded string containing the password in the process list.  Can't have that.  Is there a way to accomplish this without having the password showing in the process list?

I have tried:

```
echo $mypword|ssh -q -t $1 "base64 -d|sudo -S ls -l /root;bash -l"
```

The `ls` goes off but the shell does not remain open.

Comment: Why not configure passwordless ssh?

Comment: SSH is passwordless.  My key exists on the system.  I'm just trying to cache the password for sudo.

Comment: No... why not configure passwordless ssh straight to the root account, which is effectively what you're doing anyway. It's arguably less insecure than what you already have in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this might be done with `expect`. You can get it to retrieve the password from the environment, pass it to `base64` and recover the output. Then spawn the ssh, wait for the `$` prompt from the shell, and send it the `sudo` command. When the password prompt from sudo is seen, send the decoded password, then continue within expect in the usual way with `interact`.   Put the following in a file and make it executable, then call it with your hostname as argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422651/119298
log_user 0
spawn base64 -d
send $env(mypword)\n\x04
expect -nobrace -re "\n(.+)$"
close
set output $expect_out(1,string)

spawn ssh -q -t [lindex $argv 0] 
expect {$ }
send "sudo echo hi\n"
expect -nobrace -re {.sudo. password.*:}
send "$output\n"
expect "\n"
interact
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have enough reputation to comment. In response to:

> SSH is passwordless. My key exists on the system. I'm just trying to cache the password for sudo.

You could edit your sudoers file to allow that user account passwordless sudo privileges on that system

Comment: In the environment. This is not a possibility.